# Setting 'font-size' with jQuery not working on last element of the selected Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the `font-size` of all the selected text. It works fine but I am not able to change the font of last element in the array.

Below is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('span').mouseup(function(){
                      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                      content = range.cloneContents();
                      var select = content.querySelectorAll('span');
                      updateFont(select);
                 });
            });

            function updateFont(selectedText){
                var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
                for( i=0;i < spans.length;i++){
                    for( j=0;j < selectedText.length;j++){
                        var id = spans[i].id;
                        var   selectedId =  selectedText[j].id;
                        var  text = spans[i].innerHTML;
                        var selectedinnerText = selectedText[j].innerHTML;
                        if(i === spans.length-1)
                        {
                            checkLast(id,text,selectedText);
                        }
                        if(id === selectedId){
                            if(text === selectedinnerText){
                                $("#"+id).css("font-size",10+"px");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function checkLast(id,text,selectedText) {
                for( j=0;j < selectedText.length;j++){
                    var selectedId =  selectedText[j].id;
                    var selectedinnerText = selectedText[j].innerHTML;
                    alert(id + "  " + selectedId + " " + selectedinnerText + "  " + text);
                    if(id === selectedId){
                        if(text === selectedinnerText){
                             $("#"+id).css("font-size",10+"px");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="font-size:40px" id="one1">Hi tTheee</span> <span  style="font-size:20px" id="one2">hello</span> <span style="font-size:20px" id="one3">sdsds </span>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because your last element has a space at the end of it.

Change: `if(text === selectedinnerText){`

To:

```
if(text.trim() === selectedinnerText.trim()){ //eliminate spaces before and after the text, incase the highlighting goes over the element.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('span').mouseup(function(){
                      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                      content = range.cloneContents();
                      var select = content.querySelectorAll('span');
                      updateFont(select);
                 });
            });

            function updateFont(selectedText){
                var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
                for( i=0;i < spans.length;i++){
                    for( j=0;j < selectedText.length;j++){
                        var id = spans[i].id;
                        var   selectedId =  selectedText[j].id;
                        var  text = spans[i].innerHTML;
                        var selectedinnerText = selectedText[j].innerHTML;
                        if(i === spans.length-1)
                        {
                            checkLast(id,text,selectedText);
                        }
                        if(id === selectedId){
                            if(text.trim() === selectedinnerText.trim()){
                                $("#"+id).css("font-size",10+"px");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function checkLast(id,text,selectedText) {
                for( j=0;j < selectedText.length;j++){
                    var selectedId =  selectedText[j].id;
                    var selectedinnerText = selectedText[j].innerHTML;
                    alert(id + "  " + selectedId + " " + selectedinnerText + "  " + text);
                    if(id === selectedId){
                        if(text.trim() === selectedinnerText.trim()){
                             $("#"+id).css("font-size",10+"px");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="font-size:40px" id="one1">Hi tTheee</span> <span  style="font-size:20px" id="one2">hello</span> <span style="font-size:20px" id="one3">sdsds </span>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```